# Django-admin отображение записей через 2 many-to-many

Tags: django, orm, django-admin, many-to-many

Есть три сущности, связаны они так, как представлено на скрине:

[image: схема]

Есть ли возможность в админке при просмотре элемента А показывать все связанные с ним элементы С ?

То есть нужна связь через 2 many-to-many